# Microsoft graph unable to use $filter and $search to retrieve specific mails

Tags: java, maven, microsoft-graph-api

```
Https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user ID}/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$filter=isRead eq false
```

When I am trying to hit url from soap ui
I am unable to fetch unread mails using graph api

The response is "the content you are trying to view cannot be viewed as JSON"

IS FILTER now deprecated
Or what is solution

I tried filter and search

I am getting errors
Sometimes as cannot be viewed in json
Or invalid Node in query

Comment: Check the response format specified in the request headers. It should be Accept: application/json

Comment: Check this https://community.smartbear.com/discussions/readyapi-questions/why-i-am-still-getting-the-content-you-are-trying-to-view-cannot-be-viewed-as-js/232748